# Mysql query join with conditions

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

This is my database table , How do i query , such that i can get desired  output as below. can i query database using single query statement to get json output???

```
 Table name: rowManager
    +-------------+-----------------+----------------+
    | rowid       |      rowname    | showid         |
    +-------------+-----------------+----------------+
    |           1 | first           |              0 |
    |          17 | second          |              2 |
    |          18 | third           |              0 |
    |          20 | forth           |              0 |
    +-------------+-----------------+----------------+
    Table name: row_vid
    +-------------+----------------+-----------------+-----------------+
    | rowid       | name           |     description | submission_date |
    +-------------+----------------+-----------------+-----------------+
    |           1 | Learn PHP      | abavavaav       | 2007-05-24      |
    |          17 | Learn MySQL    | sdasdsa         | 2007-05-24      |
    |          20 | JAVA Script    | Sanjay          | 2007-05-06      |
    |           1 | JAVA           | Sanjay          | 2007-05-06      |
    |          18 | Android        | Sanjay          | 2007-05-06      |
    |          17 | ios            | Sanjay          | 2007-05-06      |
    |           1 | python         | Sanjay          | 2007-05-06      |
    |          18 | c++            | Sanjay          | 2007-05-06      |
    |          18 | c#             | Sanjay          | 2007-05-06      |
    |          17 | ruby           | Sanjay          | 2007-05-06      |
    |          18 | JQuery         | Sanjay          | 2007-05-06      |
    |          17 | objective c    | Sanjay          | 2007-05-06      |
    |           1 | JAVA Tutorial  | Sanjay          | 2007-05-06      |
    +-------------+----------------+-----------------+-----------------+



$rowQuery='SELECT * from row_vid,rowManagr  where rowManagr.showid=0';
```

i am trying to query these tables such that it gives me output like :

```
{
   "responses":{
      "First":[
         {
            "name":"Learn PHP"

         },
         {
            "name":"JAVA"

         },
         {
            "name":"python"

         },
         {
            "name":"JAVA Tutorial"
         }
      ],
      "Other Show":[
         {
            "name":"Learn MySQL"
         },
         {
            "name":"ios"
         },
         {
            "name":"ruby",

         },
         {
            "name":"objective c"
         }
      ],
      "Videos":[
         {
            "name":"Android"
         },
         {
            "name":"c++ "
         },
         {
            "name":"c#",

         },
         {
            "name":"JQuery"
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: I think you first need to take a look at joins.

Comment: i am trying but not able to get the desired output :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To start, I believe this is the query you're looking for:

```
SELECT   rowManager.rowname as category, row_vid.name as name 
FROM     rowManager, row_vid
WHERE    rowManager.rowid=row_vid.rowid
ORDER BY rowManager.rowid, row_vid.name
```

In PHP, you can do this:

```
$sql = "SELECT rowManager.rowname as category, row_vid.name as name FROM rowManager, row_vid WHERE rowManager.rowid=row_vid.rowid ORDER BY rowManager.rowid, row_vid.name"

$query_result = mysqli_query($sql);

// Piece together the $responses array, which will have [category]
// as key, while value is an array of 'name':[name]' pairs.
$responses = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_result)) {
  if (!array_key_exists($row['category'], $responses)) {
    $responses[$row['category']] = array();
  }
  array_push($responses[$row['category']], array('name' => $row['name']));
}

// Entire $response array is the value of 'responses' key in the
// final $results array.
$results = array('responses' => $responses);

// Convert $results_array to JSON and print.
print(json_encode($results));
```

Answer (score 1):

You would probably want to use [JOIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html) to structure the data you collect. But then, you would have to "manually" turn i into `JSON`. There is no built in function to `mysql` to return `JSON` data. You could either do this with your response in `php`, or use [CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) or similar to build your `JSON` response in mysql.

Your best bet to be able to debug, trace errors and to easily handle your `JSON` layout would probably to do this in `php` by iterating over your `mysql` result and building a multidimensional `array` that has similar layout and then running [json_encode](https://www.php.net/json_encode) on the array.

Answer (score 0):

If you have relation between rowManager and row_vid with column name rowid then you cant get output with these query-

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    row_vid AS rvid
        LEFT JOIN
    rowManagr rm ON rvid.rowid = rm.rowid
WHERE
    rm.showid = 0
```

After this query you will have to iterate this query result using php and format your expected data and encode this data to json using php.